# django csrf_token verification with python requests module

Tags: python, django, csrf-token

I want to send post request using **python requests** module. Since, I use **Django** for backend server. So, I need verify **csrf_token** for post method. I know that i have option to stop csrf_token verification using Django built in decorators. But, i don't want to do that for cross site protection.
My Django Sample Code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def pv(v, s):
    print(f"----------Value of {s}-------")
    print(f"Type= {type(v)}")
    print()
    print(v)
    print()

def index(request):
    pv(request.COOKIES,"HttpRequest.COOKIES")
    pv(request.headers,"HttpRequest.headers")
    token = get_token(request) # I think, Here have some worng. But What?
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

index() is work for both get and post reequest. Though i don't use redirect() for post method in sample code. Here is my get and post request code using python requests module:

```
import requests
import time

def pv(obj, s):
    print(f"-----Value of {s} --------")
    print(type(obj))
    print(obj)
    print()

url = "http://192.168.0.102:8000/home/"
data = {"a":"5", "b":4}
d = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

requests.post(url, cookies=d.cookies, data=data)

# For Test
pv(d.headers, "d.headers")
pv(d.cookies['csrftoken'], "d.cookies")
```

get request work properly and return me csrf_token.when i use this toke with post method. Django server give me **Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /home/** error and post request doesn't work properly. How can i verify csrf_token?

Comment: try `requests.post(url, cookies=d.cookies, data=data. headers={'X-CSRFToken': d.cookies['csrftoken']})`

Comment: Thanks @rzlvmp for your suggestion. it's working. Already  I solved this by another way like include csrf_token in post request data